# What is necessary for a CUDA program to run

Tags: cuda, compilation, execution

Suppose I've written a program in CUDA.

What is the output of the compilation? Is is an exe or a lib or something else?

What is necessary for a machine to run a CUDA program? (A non developer's machine / client)

E.g. compilation of a simple C++ program generates an .exe and/or .dlls.

Comment: If the answer helped you, you might want to consider clicking on the accept button and possibly on the vote up too.

Answer (score 3):

You create an assembly, just like ordinary code.
The assembly can be a dll, exe, lib or intermediate NVIDIA formats.

To run CUDA code you need the CUDA runtime libraries,
a CUDA capable device (graphics card or Tesla) and an up to date driver.